# Why is mass loaded vinyl better at reducing sound transfer through walls than acoustic foam when they both absorb sound waves?

Tags: waves, acoustics, reflection, absorption

I have done research on mass-loaded vinyl (MLV), and it says it absorbs sound. I thought that acoustic foam was the only one of the two that absorbed sound, but apparently I am wrong. If the sources that say MLV absorbs sound are correct, then why is MLV better and reducing (quieting) sound transfer through walls than acoustic foam, if they both absorb sound? Or are the sources wrong and MLV blocks sound by reflecting it, and acoustic foam is the only one of the two that absorbs sound?

Comment: There is sound propagation in all materials to varying degrees. When sound propagates in any kind of medium losses are induced as some of the acoustic energy is transformed to other kinds of energy. In order to manage to reach an educated solution you have to first define absorption in the context of your problem. As has already been stated in my answer to your previous question (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/758212/why-does-sound-absorbing-foam-stop-echoes-but-not-transmission-through-the-wall/758325#758325) absorbed energy may be thought to be anything but the reflected energy.